# Problema en actualización App Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Estimados: tengo una app desarrollada en android y subida al play store. 
El tema es que realizo actualizacines y cuando desde el equipo se busca la app en el play store no figura "actualizar". Figura "abrir", cuando ya impacto la actualización en el play store.
Para actualizar tengo que desinstalar y volver a instalar la app lo cual es incorrecto.
En el archivo build.gradle(Module:app) incremento versionCode y versionName
Actualmente versionCode 15 y versionName "1.4".

Archivo `build.gradle` de la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienen idea por que no reconoce que es una actualización?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen del play store donde se visualiza "Abrir" y no "Actualizar"

Comment: Bienvenido.Leandro., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Yo también he tenido este problema, lo he solucionado gracias a la comunidad de habla inglesa. Puedes ver la respuesta en esta enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020815/play-store-having-new-version-of-the-app-but-not-showing-update
Tienes que asegurarte de haber instalado la app desde google play y no desde Android Studio o la apk directamente. Quedo atento a tu respuesta para saber si lo has podido solucionar.

Comment: si dice "abrir" es porque ya esta instalada la aplicación, te sugiero que agregues más información , tu build.gradle, imagen de como se muestra en la tienda y esta pregunta sería más útil.

Comment: Si ya esta instalada la aplicación, por eso publique problema en actualización.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando subes una aplicación a la Play Store, esta debe ser firmada previamente con un Keystore de producción, el cual previamente creaste.

Cuando subes una aplicación desde Android Studio, esta es firmada automáticamente con el Keystore de desarrollo.

Por ejemplo si previamente instalaste la aplicación desde Google Play Store y tratas de subir la misma aplicación desde Android Studio se mostrará este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso contrario es el que comentas, instalaste la aplicación desde Android Studio y en la Play Store únicamente ves el botón "Abrir" ("Open") en lugar de "Actualizar" ("Update").

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La razón es que tienes aplicaciones firmadas con diferentes certificados.**

---

Como información extra: El `versionName` es simplemente una descripción, pero el `versionCode` es importante para indicar la versión de la aplicación e incrementarlo indicará una actualización.